# using gcc and getting core dumped

Tags: c, string, pointers, gcc, palindrome

hi i was trying to use this function to take out palindromes and make a new string with them but i get core dumped

i don't see any problem with code really it is complicated because i use so many parameters but i don't think that will make it wrong what do you think?

the result should be "noon i 313 a kayak"

```
char* Palindroms(char* str){
        int size = strlen(str);
        char *wordptr;
       char *revword;
       char *stringptr = malloc(size+1);
        for(int i = 0;i < size;i++){
             int j = 0;
             int k = 0;
            while(*str != ' '){
                wordptr[j] = *str++;
                i++;
            }
            while(j != 0){
                revword[k] = wordptr[j];
                j--;
                k++;
                }
                if(revword = wordptr)
                strcpy(stringptr + k,revword);
            }
            return stringptr;
        }

int main(){
    char string1[] = "yesterday noon i paid 313 shekels for a new kayak";
    char *string3 = Palindroms(string1);
    printf("%s", string3);

    return 0;
```

Comment: Did not look too deep, but this does not look right: `if(revword = wordptr)`

Comment: `revword = wordptr`? Really?

Comment: Single step through the code with a debugger and see where it crashes.

Comment: so how can i check if two words match?

Comment: You never initialized revword and wordptr

Comment: = is assignment, == is comparison

Comment: First of all `=` is an assignment operator. Comparison is `==`. Second, strings cannot be compared this way, there is `strcmp` function for that.

Comment: @AdhamJab Check the duplicate link I provided on top of your question. You have to use the strcmp function.

Comment: wow didn't really see that i put single = that's embarrassing

Comment: `while( j != 0 )`, `j` is always `0`